# Error while running angular project in Visual Studio code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am getting these errors while running a newly created Angular project in Visual Studio Code

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'C:/C#/Angular/AngularApp/src/app/app.component.css?ngResource' in
> 'C:\C#\Angular\AngularApp'
>
> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'C:\C#\Angular\AngularApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true'
> in 'C:\C#\Angular\AngularApp'
>
> Error: The loader "C:/C#/Angular/AngularApp/src/app/app.component.css"
> didn't return a string.

I just created a new project with the name AngularApp. When I run it using ng serve command I am getting errors

Comment: Can you provide the angular version?

Comment: Did you copy any code from anywhere else that you are using?   This usually occurs when you set up a project to use SCSS but copy CSS component code into it.

Comment: Please provide the app component.ts and package.json file and root level component if there is any

Comment: Angular CLI: 15.0.4
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 9.2.0
OS: win32 x64

Comment: and the app.component.ts file plz

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularApp';
}

Answer (score 0):

It's character '#' in the folder's name in the project path, try removing it. after removing It should work fine.

**Modification should be:**

```
C:/C#/Angular/AngularApp/src/app/app.component.css
```

**To this:**

```
C:/CSharp/Angular/AngularApp/src/app/app.component.css
```

Comment: Solved the problem! Thanks